# How can I specify a numeric pattern with dashes in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For this code, I'm trying to get the user to input a pattern of numbers like "####-##-###" including the dashes. I have this code but it's returning an error.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your student number: ");
        int su;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{4,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{2,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{3,}");
        su = s.nextInt();
        String input = String.valueOf(su);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.matches()){
            System.out.println("You have successfully logged in.\nWelcome to your new dashboard!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid format. Try Again.");
        }
    }
}
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217)
 at com.mycompany.studentnumber.StudentNumber.main(StudentNumber.java:21)
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the error.

Comment: the error is
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217)
 at com.mycompany.studentnumber.StudentNumber.main(StudentNumber.java:21)
Command execution failed.

And a bunch of org.apache... errors

Comment: Your pattern has a lot going on. If you just want to match that specific format, why not `"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}"`?

Comment: its still returning the error

Comment: Perhaps it's due to calling `nextInt()`? You're scanning the next input token as an int but you're also expecting it to be `####-##-###`, so that seems at odds to me

Comment: try to use online regex tester like https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you have the dashes in the string and you're calling `nextInt`. You need to read the input as a string (with e.g. `nextLine`) then apply the regex to that and convert the parts to integers as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> `su = s.nextInt();`

Since the input you expect contains dashes, i.e. `-`, it isn't an `int`, it's a string, so use method [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) (rather than method `nextInt`).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StudentNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your student number: ");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{4,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{2,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{3,}");
        String input = s.nextLine();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.matches()){
            System.out.println("You have successfully logged in.\nWelcome to your new dashboard!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Invalid format. Try Again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is output from a sample run:

```
Enter your student number: 123-456-789
Invalid format. Try Again.
```

Here is another sample run:

```
Enter your student number: 1234-56-789
You have successfully logged in.
Welcome to your new dashboard!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since,you are using `-` in `int` input, input cant't take it as integer, instead of it use `next()` method of Scanner() class.

`String input = in.next()`

Also, if you are using

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{4,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{2,}+[-?]{1,1}+[\\d]{3,}");`

It also validates `111111-11-11111`. To avoid this use instead

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{4}+[-?]{1}+[\\d]{2}+[-?]{1}+[\\d]{3}");`